# Mount NFS on a MAC : Could not parse file system specification

Tags: macos, debian

I use to be able to mount a directory on my debian virtual machine without any problems. Today  however, when I try to run this:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 10.1.1.45/home/dev /Users/myusername/LocalServer
```

I get the following error :

```
mount_nfs: could not parse file system specification
```

Any ideas whats happening here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a colon in `10.1.1.45:/home/dev`.

Comment: Good catch! But after trying that, I'm now getting mount_nfs: can't mount /home/dev from 10.1.1.45 onto /Users/myusername/LocalServer: Permission denied.

Comment: I had to use `insecure` in the export options here because the mount request doesn't come from a (not-really-)"secure" port (defined as one < 1024, which Unixes only allow `root` to `bind()` — no such restriction exists on Windows, which makes it largely historical and pointless).

Comment: Pointless on a single user system like Windows, yes, but Unix was designed at the outset as a multiuser system.  You don't want non-privileged processes binding to, say, TCP port 25 and slurping up everyone's e-mail.